# Can't run bash: tgetnum: symbol not found

Tags: shell-script, docker

After creating a Docker image I can't run bash, sh and other commands. Today I realize I can't even run the make ( some conditions I can't see now ). This is the error I've got:

```
Making all in data
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/local/proj/data'
Make proj.db
rm -f proj.db
Error relocating /usr/lib/libreadline.so.8: tgetnum: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/libreadline.so.8: tgoto: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/libreadline.so.8: tgetflag: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/libreadline.so.8: tputs: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/libreadline.so.8: tgetent: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/libreadline.so.8: tgetstr: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/libreadline.so.8: BC: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/libreadline.so.8: PC: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/libreadline.so.8: UP: symbol not found
Build of proj.db failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/proj/data'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:665: proj.db] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:486: all-recursive] Error 1
```

and this is the Dockerfile to the image that caused all this trouble (in wich I can't run /bin/bash )

https://github.com/icemagno/gdaljava/blob/main/DockerfileGrads

I have no knowledge in linux so I don't even know what to put here to ask for help. You can ask for more information but please don't downvote because of this.

I can see some "readline" stuff in [Dockerfile here](https://github.com/icemagno/gdaljava/blob/161bdd068fe092f71e0680f629d91d07ba7a15b2/DockerfileGrads#L45)

Comment: The build script lists `ncurses-dev`, but not `ncurses`.  If it's really self-contained, you'll need **`ncurses`** (or whatever system-dependent name is used, e.g., `ncurses6`).

Comment: Can be this the origin of this problem or you are only givin me an advice?

Comment: There's no distinction: if programs running in your image don't have access to libncurses, you'll get that error message.

Comment: Well... adding ```ncurses``` didn't solved the problem anyway.... can't even run an instance using ```/bin/bash```. Got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem by removing the `readline` install. I don't know for what it is used and may discover later when try to use GRADS (my image).

Don't know how to solve the root of the problem and may come back here again if I pay the price for removing this package.

I see the script install READLINE twice. One from apk add and other by building:

```
RUN wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/snapshot/readline-master.tar.gz \
    && tar xf readline-master.tar.gz \
    && cd readline-master \
    && ./configure --prefix=/usr \
    && make -j4 \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf readline-master \
    && rm -rf readline-master.tar.gz
```

but can't tell if this is causing the problem because I have no more time to test. If other users arrive here for the same error I tell them to try changing the readline install.

```
  +-------------------------------+
  |                               |
  |  GrADS will be built with:    |
  |                               |
  |  - GUI disabled               |
  |  - READLINE disabled          |
  |  - GEOTIFF disabled           |
  |  + SHAPEFILE enabled          |
  |  + GD enabled                 |
  |  + CAIRO enabled              |
  |  - GRIB2 disabled             |
  |  - HDF4 disabled              |
  |  + HDF5 enabled               |
  |  + NETCDF3 enabled            |
  |  - OPeNDAP disabled           |
  |                               |
  +-------------------------------+
```